# How to use androidx.fragment.app.DialogFragment in android.app.fragment

Tags: android-fragments, dialog, androidx, android-dialogfragment

I have created a DialogFragment using `androidx.fragment.app.DialogFragment`. I want to display that dialog fragment inside `android.app.fragment`. How could we achieve that? Any workaround or best practice?

I tried androidxDialog.show(getFragmentManager(), TAG);, but `getFragmentManager()` is inside `android.app.fragment`. So it won't work